# PHP Arrays- 4 Separate arrays but only want to return one value

Tags: php, arrays

Take a look at these arrays

```
Array( 
[CompInvId] => 17 [Item] => w [Qty] => w [Tax_Rate] => 10 [Price] => w [ss] => w 
) 
Array( 
[CompInvId] => 17 [Item] => 4 [Qty] => 4 [Tax_Rate] => 10 [Price] => 4 [ss] => 4 
) 
Array( 
[CompInvId] => 17 [Item] => 4 [Qty] => 4 [Tax_Rate] => 10 [Price] => 4 [ss] => 4 
)
Array(
[CompInvId] => 17 [Item] => 4 [Qty] => 4 [Tax_Rate] => 20 [Price] => 4 [ss] => 4 
)
```

How do I get just the value 17 from all of them?

Comment: How are these arrays stored? Each in a separate variable? in an array?

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = array_column($array,'CompInvId');
print_r($a);
```

Here $array would be your primary array ( which mentioned in question).

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` to iterate through the array

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val) // $arr is your array
{
  $val['CompInvId'];
}
```